# Did Lancelot surpass Meliodas in power?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In the Nanatsu no Taizai wikia, they claim something which hasnt happened in the anime yet,

> Meliodas and Tristan fight Arthur and they lose, but Lancelot fights Arthur and the battle end "indecisive"

What happened in those battles?

Did Lancelot surpass Meliodas in power?